# Bower: run build system

Tags: gruntjs, npm, gulp, bower

Is it possible run "grunt" or "gulp" automatically during installation with bower?

to generate the compiled version of the package without including a compiled version in the git repository.

For example:

> I install a github package called: foo/bar, I use: ***bower install foo/bar***
>
> I get the source code that has a Gruntfile.json file that compiles the source code in a single file called main.js. How do I get bower run "npm install && grunt" automatically

Comment: Do you mean 'grunt' or 'gulp' command to install packages and generate the complied version of them? Bower installation comes with git repos usually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would help if you could give a clearer use case, but you can use bower's [install hooks](https://github.com/bower/bower/blob/master/HOOKS.md) to run an arbitrary command on install.

```
// .bowerrc
{
    "scripts": {
        "postinstall": "gulp build",
    }
}
```

`preinstall`, `postinstall,` and `preuninstall` are supported.